# How to apply H (homography matrix) to a list of x,y coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, homography

I have obtained a homography matrix H after applying it on a some coordinates from 2 images.

```
[[ 9.62122460e-02  4.19126557e-01  2.78378319e+02]
 [ 2.84972076e-02  1.04148707e+00 -2.60554265e+01]
 [-7.03233591e-05  2.00171167e-03  1.00000000e+00]]
```

Now i want to apply this matrix to each x,y coordinate in a list, how can i do this in python ?

```
x = [336.0, 21.0, 874.0, 407.0, 671.0, 587.0, 153.5, 1030.5, 1032.5, 663.5, 793.5]

y = [179.0, 205.0, 166.0, 148.0, 300.0, 93.0, 185.0, 214.0, 312.0, 182.0, 402.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Basic theory section here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html#basic_theory) you can just multiplicate with the stacked list of `x`, `y`, and a row of `1`s:

```
import numpy as np

h = np.array([[ 9.62122460e-02, 4.19126557e-01, 2.78378319e+02],
              [ 2.84972076e-02, 1.04148707e+00, -2.60554265e+01],
              [-7.03233591e-05, 2.00171167e-03, 1.00000000e+00]])
x = [336.0, 21.0, 874.0, 407.0, 671.0, 587.0, 153.5, 1030.5, 1032.5, 663.5, 793.5]
y = [179.0, 205.0, 166.0, 148.0, 300.0, 93.0, 185.0, 214.0, 312.0, 182.0, 402.0]

xy1 = np.vstack([x, y, np.full_like(x, 1.)])

result = h @ xy1
```

Result:

```
array([[385.72928736, 366.31972035, 432.04283047, 379.56743356,
        468.67470317, 373.8336772 , 370.68531181, 467.2181217 ,
        508.48494878, 418.49617759, 523.21161211],
       [169.94582078, 188.04786421, 171.73798656, 139.68302335,
        305.5123208 ,  87.53073187, 170.99400282, 226.18917891,
        328.31190619, 182.40311748, 415.23490987],
       [  1.33467774,   1.4088741 ,   1.27082152,   1.26763172,
          1.55332653,   1.14487937,   1.35952202,   1.35589808,
          1.55192517,   1.31765198,   1.74888651]])
```